# PHP Form submit to display response on form page

Tags: php

I have a web form (`form.php`) in PHP which has following layout:

```
<form method="post" action="mailer.php" class="form-horizontal">
```

`mailer.php` has a function that checks for data, validates it and send email to me. After this all is done successfully I want to redirect to my form page with an alert/info message.

Mailer function in `mailer.php` looks like:

```
    $httpReferer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    print_r("Form submitted successfully. We will contact you soon !");
    header('Location: '. $httpReferer) ;
```

I want to get the message in `print_r` on `form.php` in the following `div`,

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    Make sure to fill all the fields with correct values before sending your email!
</div>
```

I am able to redirect back, but without any message. Tried echo, tried using JavaScript alerts etc. None worked for me.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the edit, do we always highlight filenames ?

Comment: Use session and store you message in a variable, for example :
$_SESSION['message'].
Or use Cokkies and then store your message in a variable too, for example :
$_COOKIE['message'].

Comment: @CodeMonkey, many users use backticks for file names (and I find it much easier to read). Some people **bold them** instead (or as well). I wouldn't have bothered editing just for that, but the `print_r` and `div` deserved backticks, so I made the other changes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mailer.php` script, you can either print a message or use `header()`, you can't do both.  If you want to redirect to `form.php` and include a message with it, you can either use `$_GET` or `$_SESSION`.  Using `$_GET` would look like this:

```
$httpReferer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$message = "Form submitted successfully. We will contact you soon !";
header('Location: '. $httpReferer . "?message=" . urlencode( $message ));
```

Then your `div` would look like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <?php echo $_GET['message']; ?>
</div>
```

But I think the `$_SESSION` solution would be cleaner because it won't clutter the address bar with your message:

```
$httpReferer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = "Form submitted successfully. We will contact you soon !";
header('Location: '. $httpReferer);

<? session_start(); ?>
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['message']; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: $_SESSION is coming out to be NULL

Comment: The original answer assumed you already had sessions started elsewhere in your scripts, but I've modified the answer with the appropriate `session_start()`s.

Comment: That works. Thanks. Can i also change classes somehow from the mailer script ?

Comment: You can set as many `$_SESSION` variables as you'd like in `mailer.php`, and them use them in `form.php`, so that would probably be a good place to hold your classes if that's where you want them to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

instead of redirecting with php do it with javascript. replace header('Location') with,

```
echo <<<SCRIPT

<script>
setTimeout(function(){

document.location = '$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]';   
}, 2000);

</script>

SCRIPT;
```